# Grep without duplicates?

Tags: text-processing, command-line, grep

I have multiple revisions of a text file in separate files in the same folder.

How can I *`grep`* all files in that folder without listing any duplicate of lines with identical text?

Comment: What's your desired output ? Just the lines that match a certain pattern, without any filename prepended ? If so, you should be able to find the answer yourself...

Comment: An example would clarify the question.

Comment: @Kusalananda - I wonder why none of the upvoters here takes the time to reply and enlighten us... This question "is clear" and "shows research effort" ?

Comment: @Don_crissti Desired output? Filename: Can but does not have to.

Comment: is clear: no exact duplicates in output lines (sort -u is the reply for removing duplicates)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

How about

```
cat * | grep exampletext | sort -u
```

Comment: This works but `cat` isn't necessary. All you need is: `grep -H /path/to/files/* | sort -u`.

Comment: @ Nasir Riley: accepted - but it would be `-h` to `Suppress the prefixing of file names on output`.

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
grep -h test files* | puniq
```

`puniq` is: `perl -ne '$seen{$_}++ or print;'`

It is similar to `sort -u` but it does not sort the input and it gives output while running.

If you want the file name and avoid duplicate lines in each file:

```
parallel --tag --lb 'grep string {} | puniq' ::: files*
```

If you want the file name and do not want duplicate lines from any of the files (File names must not contain TAB (\t)):

```
parallel --tag --lb grep string {} ::: files* |
  perl -ne '/^[^\t]+(.*)/ and $seen{$1}++ or print;'
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this could be close to what you imagine (works with gnu awk):

```
cat file1
1
2
3
22

cat file11
1
2
3
8
9

cat file111
1
2
3
5
6

awk '{seen[$0]++;fname[$0]=FILENAME};END{for (k in seen) {if (seen[k]==1) print fname[k],":",k}}' file1*
file111 : 5
file111 : 6
file11 : 8
file11 : 9
file1 : 22
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the result into sort to filter duplicates.

```
grep -re pattern files and dirs ... | sort -ut: -k2
```

The `-t:` and `-k2` options of sort will cause it to ignore the file name when doing the sorting and merging.

Or, if you don't want the filenames, simply:

```
grep -hre pattern files and dirs ... | sort -u
```

Comment: You are missing the files that you are going to `grep`.

Comment: and then, once you supply multiple filenames, the filenames themselves would destroy the purpose of `sort -u`...

Comment: come on, both `sort` and `uniq` have the ability to consider only some fields; this answer could be improved: `grep -re pattern files and dirs | sort -ut: -k2`

Comment: Caveat: Will give wrong output if file names contain `:`.

Comment: @OleTange it would only give false positives in that case (it would write more than once a line that it should print only once). That's an acceptable compromise. If you omit the `-t:` it will have the same problem with filenames that contain spaces -- I think that filenames with spaces are more common than files with colons.

Comment: @OleTange and even that could be worked around with GNU non-standard features: `grep -Zre pattern dir | sort -ut'\0' -k2 | gawk '{gsub(/\0/,": ");print}'`

Comment: I can still live with `sort -u`. Much better than duplicates scattered around.

Comment: @neverMind9 what do you mean by 'duplicates scattered around'? If you really have filenames containing colons and those files match the pattern (which is **highly** unlikely), then you could use the script from my comment [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/484086/grep-without-duplicates#comment886933_484090)